# Drools - load KJAR from classpath or dependency related at pom.xml

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I'm developing a BPM application with Drools, integrated inside a Spring boot project. To create a kContainer object I'm using the @KContainer annotation:

```
@KContainer
@KReleaseId(groupId = "group", artifactId = "kjar", version = "LATEST")
private KieContainer kContainer;
```

In local and QA environments Drools search the kjar artifact using maven in a remote repository and all works fine. But, for security reasons, in production environment, it's not possible to search the artifact, because the server cannot have access to the maven repository. I'm including into the pom.xml file the dependency for kjar project, but when I review the logs, I can see that it's avoiding to search in classpath.

My question is, how can I force to Drools to load the KJAR dependency from the classpath and libraries inside de project jar instead of make requests to maven's repository?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have added kjar in your classpath.

Drools KIE API provides a mechanism to load kjar from the classpath. Hope below java code snippets help you to create KIE container using classpath kjar.

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
```

Comment: Hi Sakthivel. Thanks for your answer.
I trIed to do that, but when the KJAR is an external file, and it's loaded into the project in pom.xml file, for any unkown reason it doesn't work. My solution was to extract drl files and kmodule.xml as a maven task in construction, but I'm not entirely convinced of this solution. I hope you can know why the project cannot recognize and load rules when they are loaded in this way. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever found a definitive solution? Everything works on Eclipse but when trying to run the Spring Boot app we have the same problem.